# Django autocomplete light Creation of new choices

Tags: django, autocomplete

I installed autocomplete light and add the according to this tutorial : https://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.io/en/master/tutorial.html

**models.py :**

```
 class Stocks(models.Model):

  user=models.ForeignKey(User, null=True)
  name=models.CharField(max_length=128,verbose_name=_('stockname'))
  number=models.CharField(blank=True,null=True,max_length=64,verbose_name=_('number'))
  suffix=models.CharField(blank=True,null=True,max_length=12,verbose_name=_('uffix'))
  comment=models.CharField(blank=True,null=True,max_length=264,verbose_name=_('comment'))

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.name)+ '-' +str(self.number)
class Meta:
    verbose_name=_('Stock')
    verbose_name_plural=_('Stocks')
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('BallbearingSite:mystocks' )
```

**forms.py :**

```
 class StocksForm(forms.ModelForm):
    name=forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Stocks.objects.values_list('name', flat=True).distinct(),label=_('name'))
     class Meta():
    model=Stocks
    fields=('name','number','suffix','brand','comment','price')
    widgets = {
        'name': autocomplete.ModelSelect2(url='stock-autocomplete')
    }
```

**views.py:**

```
 #stock view is for saving in db
 def stock(request):
  stocks_form=StocksForm(None)
  if request.method == "POST":
    stocks_form =StocksForm(data=request.POST)
    if stocks_form.is_valid():
        instance=stocks_form.save()
        instance.user=request.user
        instance.save()
        messages.success(request,"Registered Successfuly" ,extra_tags="savestock")
    else:
        messages.error(request, "ERROR!")

else:
    stocks_form=StocksForm()
return render(request,'BallbearingSite/stock.html',{'stocks_form':stocks_form})

 #AUTOCOMPLETE
class StocksAutocomplete(autocomplete.Select2QuerySetView):
def get_queryset(self):
    # Don't forget to filter out results depending on the visitor !
    if not self.request.user.is_authenticated():
        return Stocks.objects.none()
    qs = Stocks.objects.all()
    if self.q:
        qs = qs.filter(name__istartswith=self.q)
    return qs
```

**urls.py :**
    url(r'^stock/$',views.stock,name='stock'),
    url(r'^stock-autocomplete/$',views.StocksAutocomplete.as_view(create_field='name'),name='stock-autocomplete',),

**template.html :**

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" >
{% csrf_token %}
{{ stocks_form.as_p }}
{{form.media }}

 {% block javascript %}
<input id="savestocks" type="submit" name="" value="submit">
</form>

 <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/jquery-1.12.4.min.js'  %}">
 </script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/jquery-ui.min.js' %}">
</script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/jquery-ui.css' %}">

 {% endblock %}
```

it was written in tutorial to add `(create_field='name')` in url to be able to add new choice to autocomplete list but the autocomplete in my form is like a dropdownlist and i can not write anything in it .
it is like this :

[image]

Comment: I found that the `StocksAutocomplete` view is not executing in my codes and when i delete `class StocksAutocomplete(autocomplete.Select2QuerySetView): ....` view nothing changed!!!! also when i delete the `    widgets = {
        'name': autocomplete.ModelSelect2(url='stock-autocomplete')
    }`  nothing get changed !!!

Comment: i deleted `name=forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Stocks.objects.values_list('name', flat=True).distinct(),label=_('name'))` from the FORM.PY then an error says :  `Reverse for 'stock_autocomplete' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []` it seems there is some conflict in `stock ` view and the `widget `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was becouse i used this line in forms.py and it became like dropdownlist :

```
 name=forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Stocks.objects.values_list('name',   flat=True).distinct(),label=_('name'))
 class Meta():
```